# How to count the co-occurrence of two strings in two files using bash?

Tags: regex, string, bash

I have two files, file1 and file2 and it is guaranteed that these two files have the same number of lines.
Now, I want to count the total number of co-occurrence of "key1" in file1 and "key2" in file2 in each sentence in bash.

I don't think this explanation is not enough, so let me explain using an example.
Let's say, file1 is consisted of the following sentences:

```
this is a sentence
this sentence is really short
I like the sentence
```

File2 is consisted of the following sentences:

```
I am a dog
The dog is barking at me
The dog is gazing at another dog
```

If "key1" is `sentence` and "key2" is `dog` then,

- first sentence pair: co-occurrence is 1.
- second sentence pair: co-occurrence is also 1.
- third sentence pair: co-occurrence is 2. This case is a bit tricky, but I define that if a sentence pair have multiple occurrences of "key1" and "key2", then co-occurrence is (occurrence of "key1")*(occurrence of "key2").

In total, the co-occurrence is 4.

Is there any easy way to achieve this?

Comment: If:  `(occurrence of "key1")*(occurrence of "key2")` - the third is: 0 for sentence and 2 for dog.  Why is 2 the result when  `0 * 2 = 0`?

Comment: Opps sorry I will fix that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work using gawk

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[FNR]=gsub(/sentence/,"")}
     FNR!=NR{b[FNR]=gsub(/dog/,"")}
     END{for(i in a)x+=(a[i]*b[i]);print x}' file file2
```

---

#### Output

```
4
```

---

#### How it works

```
FNR==NR
```

If the File record number matches the total Record number,i.e it is in the first file

```
a[FNR]=gsub(/sentence/,"")
```

Increment array `a` with the File record number as a key with the result from the gsub.
This uses the fact that gsub returns the number of matches it made to the changing field.
As you only wanted the number i just replace them with nothing.

```
 FNR!=NR{b[FNR]=gsub(/dog/,"")}
```

Same principle, just this time searching for `dog` and putting it in array `b`.

```
 END{for(i in a)x+=(a[i]*b[i]);print x}'
```

`END` indicates that this block is executed after all file have been processed.
Loop through all elements in array a(as both files have the same number of line this should be the same number as b).
For each element increment `x` with the result from multiplying the element from both `a` and `b` together.
When the loop is finished print `x`.

---

Slightly shorter way

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[FNR]=gsub(/sentence/,"")}
     FNR!=NR{x+=(a[FNR]*=gsub(/dog/,""))}
     END{print x}' file file2
```

Comment: How powerful `awk` is! Thank you very much for your detailed explanation.

Comment: @fedorqui Someone was vote fixing and downvoting all my posts so i deleted it, then they got banned though so i made a new one :)